# NSSortDescriptor with fetched property core data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I have an `Agency` entity that has a fetched property `city`. I'm performing a fetch request and I want my results to be sorted by agency's `name` and by city's `name`.

This is the part of old code. As you can see there was a relationship to the entity `City` and I could setup my sort descriptor easily. But now I've replaced relationship by fetched property.

Help me please, how I need to modify this code?

```
self.context = //...

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *callEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Agency" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:callEntity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortByCityNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"city.name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSSortDescriptor *sortByNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortByCityNameDescriptor, sortByNameDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

//performing a fetch
```

Comment: Do you no longer have the relationship with `City`? If so, sorting with a sort descriptor won't be possible as you attempt to do it. A fetched property is not a replacement for a relationship.

Comment: @user1897723 Actually you need to say your problem little more clearly.. Try again.

Comment: @Leo How can I solve my problem without a relationship? Can I sort fetched results _after_ they were fetched by fetched property?

Comment: You can, but that would be slow. You can sort the results array.

Comment: Please, answer with the piece of sorting code, I'll make it as the best.